# Word breaking not following text alignment

Tags: html, css

I have an html that I need to display the wrapping of the sentence in a block, but its floating left.
[image: result]

I would like to have the rest of the string (the piece thats not being displayed b/c its overflow) to be shown bellow the "very" word.

**HTML**

```
<body class='login'><div id="header">
            <div id="branding">
                 <h1 id="site-name"><a href="/">very long string that needs to be better displayed</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div></body>
```

**CSS**

```
#header #branding h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-indent: 190px;
    background: white url(https://via.placeholder.com/150) 5px 0px no-repeat;
    height: 136px;
    width: 150px;
    background-size: 150px;
    white-space: pre;
}
.login #header h1 a {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

if I try the `overflow-wrap:break-word` it displays it like this:

[image: result of overflow-wrap]

Comment: text-indent works only on the first line, you need to use padding-left instead

Comment: Put padding instead of `text-indent`. Now it indents only first line, while padding will "indent" all lines

Comment: @TemaniAfif it worked! I will accept your answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding-left` since `text-indent` will affect only the first line. Don't forget to add `box-sizing:border-box;` to consider the padding inside the width:

```css
#header #branding h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 190px;
    background: white url(https://via.placeholder.com/150) 5px 0px no-repeat;
    width: 600px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-size: 150px;
}
.login #header h1 a {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
            <div id="branding">
                 <h1 id="site-name"><a href="/">very long string that needs to be better displayed</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div></body>
```